# When loop throgh HtmlTableElement and converting to json it convert only first table json object.but not socond object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple tables. when looping through each table.innerHtml print all tables one by one.but when convert into object it only gives one table object.

```
$( ".table" ).each(function( index ,e) {
    let tableId = $(this).closest('table').attr('id')
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    console.table(table.innerHTML+"tb");
    let myObj = {
        table: [],
        add_rows: []
    };
    for (var i = 0; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       let tr_obj = [];
       for (var j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
          var drop_down = $("#drop\\[" + j + "\\]").val()
          var text_value = $("#text\\[" + i + "\\]\\[" + j + "\\]").val();
          tr_obj.push(create_object(drop_down, text_value));
        }
        myObj['table'].push(tr_obj);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj['table'])+"ttt")
    var div="div"+tableId
    var hidden="entry_field_"+tableId+""
    document.getElementById(hidden).value = JSON.stringify(myObj).replace(/\\/g, "")
});
```

when we console `table.InnerHtml` it gives print both table.but MyObj gives same table object.

Comment: Could you create a simple fiddle with that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/samjad20/3am12dr6/14/

Comment: And explain me please what output should be in document.getElementById(hidden).value

Comment: Table id table[6] should store in text box id entry_field_table[6]  and Table id table[7] should store in text box id entry_field_table[7]  with updated json data

Comment: is it because of same textbox ids in both tables?

Comment: @samjadps the answer below isn't useful to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've improved your fiddle and `myObj` is created correctly (in `table` property are rows from both tables). But if you want render this object in json format you have to redesign this object or render the same object in two tables. If you want render two objects with different `tables` prop you have to convert `myObj` in to separate objects. Look on my fiddle:

```
table.forEach((e,i)=>{
  let tr_obj = [];
  Array.from(e.rows).forEach((ele,ind)=>{
    let cells = []
    Array.from(ele.cells).forEach((element,index)=>{
      let drop_down = $("#drop\\[" + i + "\\]\\[" + ind + "\\]\\[" + index + "\\]").val();
      let text_value = $("#text\\[" + i + "\\]\\[" + ind + "\\]\\[" + index + "\\]").val();
      cells.push(create_object(drop_down, text_value));
    })
    tr_obj.push(cells)
  });
  myObj['table'].push(tr_obj);
});
```

And fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wa3vbsc6/2/

Comment: @samjadps Have you found another solution to your problem?